# Use TF 2.1 install in user directory

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I have an existing tensorflow 1.13.1 installation in `/opt/conda`, which I do not have permission to uninstall. When I do a `pip install tensorflow==2.1 --user --upgrade`, it goes to the user folder `/home/myuser/.local/bin/tf_upgrade_v2`. When I run

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.__version
```

it still gives 1.13.1. Is there any way for me to invoke the tensorflow 2.1 installed in `/home/myuser/.local/bin/tf_upgrade_v2`?

Comment: Could you add the contents of `sys.path`? Usually these errors are due to the ordering of directories in `sys.path`.

Comment: @SergeiLebedev Tried, have put that as the first item in `sys.path`, but it still does not work.

Comment: Did you do that before importing TF? It could be imported implicitly by other dependencies: double-check if it's in `sys.modules` prior to manipulating `sys.path`. It might also be useful to share your `sys.meta_path`.